# Profile of User Triggering Email Alert Limits Recipents

Tags: email-alert

I have an email alert on a custom object that sends to a list of salesforce users, including the triggering user and me (the sys admin). The email alert sends out as desired, however when the triggering user is in a certain profile the email alert only sends to the triggering user and me (sys admin). If the triggering user is in other profiles the email alert does not exhibit this behavior, and thus the email goes out to all intended users.

The email logs show that salesforce never even tried to send the email out to the users, theres no rows for them in the email logs (just rows for the triggering user and me (sys admin).

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this strange behavior?

Comment: does the errant profile have 'send email' permission?

Comment: The user in question may not have view access to the other user records.

Comment: @AdrianLarson public read/write on the object. Not an access issue unfortuntely. :(

Comment: @cropredy They have 'send email'. This issue suddenly appeared over the weekend, all other email alerts function. The issue is unique to this one email alert and seems to be intermittant.